# why am i getting a StackOverflowException when testing a GridViewPager with Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, wear-os, robolectric

i'm trying to add a test for the activity in the android wear implementation and getting a stack overflow exception.

the test:

```
@Test
public void testActivityInit() {
       Robolectric.buildActivity(CustomGridActivity.class).create().start().visible().get();
}
```

the exception:

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.compareAndSwapInt(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.compareAndSetState(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:566)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.nonfairTryAcquire(ReentrantLock.java:137)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.tryLock(ReentrantLock.java:370)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:432)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(ClassLoader.java:464)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:405)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.ShadowWrangler.stripStackTrace(ShadowWrangler.java:331)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.RobolectricInternals.cleanStackTrace(RobolectricInternals.java:28)
    ...
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(Scheduler.java:246)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.runOneTask(Scheduler.java:167)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.advanceTo(Scheduler.java:148)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.advanceToLastPostedRunnable(Scheduler.java:111)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.unPause(Scheduler.java:42)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.unPause(ShadowLooper.java:271)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:311)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowViewGroup.addView(ShadowViewGroup.java:35)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3709)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.inflate(WatchViewStub.java:179)
    at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.onMeasure(WatchViewStub.java:133)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.measureChild(GridViewPager.java:1363)
    at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.onMeasure(GridViewPager.java:1334)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:447)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)

i've found various reference projects that test android wear, so the basics do work.  it seems like the exception is in how the GridViewPager is handled/implemented.  has anyone else run in to anything like this or have a fix/workaround?

thanks.

Comment: What version of `Robolectric`? Can you post your code for `CustomGridActivity`?

Comment: Robolectric 3.0-rc.  I talked to the Robolectric guys and they haven't implemented wear support yet.

Comment: Did you not try my answer?